# Multiple light sources in HLSL

Tags: directx, hlsl

I am learning shader programming. I've got some basics down, but multiple light sources with different types are challenging. Do I need to use a single render pass for each light type or multiple passes? Or, if there are valid reasons for both, what are the use cases for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use a separate pass for each light type if you are using forward rendering.  You would perform lighting for all lights in the same shader. If you used defered rendering then you would render each light type in a separate pass.